# Cache<K, BlockingDeque<V>> combined with Striped<Lock>: how to lock the whole cache

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, guava

I've got something like this:

```
private Striped<ReadWriteLock> stripes = Striped.lazyWeakReadWriteLock(STRIPES_AMOUNT);

private final Cache<Long, BlockingDeque<Peer>> peers = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(PEER_ACCESS_TIMEOUT_MIN, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build();
```

Each time I proceed operation on cache, I lock it with help of `stripes`.

**example#1 [write operation]**

```
public void removePeers(long sessionId) {
    Lock lock = stripes.get(sessionId).writeLock();
    lock.lock();
    try {
        peers.invalidate(sessionId);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

**example#2 [read operation]**

```
public BlockingDeque<Peer> getPeers(long sessionId) {
    Lock lock = stripes.get(sessionId).readLock();
    lock.lock();
    try {
        return peers.getIfPresent(sessionId);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

**example#3 [write operation]**

```
public boolean addPeer(Peer peer) {
    long key = peer.getSessionId();
    Lock lock = stripes.get(key).writeLock();
    lock.lock();
    try {
        BlockingDeque<Peer> userPeers = peers.getIfPresent(key);
        if (userPeers == null) {
            userPeers = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Peer>();
            peers.put(key, userPeers);
        }
        return userPeers.offer(peer);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

**Question:** *What is the most efficient way to lock the method below?*

```
/**
 * I should get the whole peers in cache
 */
public BlockingDeque<Peer> getAllPeers() {
    BlockingDeque<Peer> result = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Peer>();
    for (BlockingDeque<Peer> deque : peers.asMap().values()) {
        result.addAll(deque);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you want to lock the whole cache, rather than providing a weakly consistent view, you might have to add another read-write lock for the whole cache.  But a weakly consistent view might be acceptable.

Comment: @LouisWasserman but how hsould I synchronize that separate r-w lock with my `Striped<Lock>`. Or maybe I can iterate through the whole `Striped<Lock>` and lock all locks? can you answer with example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way is not to lock at all :)

See my updated answer in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/43304/37969): you don't need a `ReadWriteLock`, hence you don't need to lock the reads.

When you read (in Thread 1 for example), you get a snapshot of what's in the cache at that moment. If you have concurrent modifications (in Thread 2), even if you use locks, the content of the cache might have changed before Thread 1 finishes its computation and the lock doesn't buy you anything:

```
    Thread 1             Thread 2
       |                    |
   getAllPeers              |
       |                 addPeer
Do something with           |
the Peers but not           |
  the added one             |
       |                    |
```

So your implementation of `getAllPeers()` is fine as it is.

---

As a side note, if you need to lock all the stripes in a `Striped<Lock>`, you could do it using [`getAt()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html#getAt%28int%29), but the naive way could get you into trouble if one of the `lock()` calls throws an unchecked exception ([which is permitted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#lock%28%29)):

```
for (int i = 0, size = stripes.size(); i++; i < size) {
    stripes.getAt(i).lock();
}
try {
    // Do something
} finally {
    for (int i = 0, size = stripes.size(); i++; i < size) {
        stripes.getAt(i).unlock();
    }
}
```

An alternative way would be to do it recursively, but it increases the length of the stack by the number of stripes, so you could get a `StackOverflowException` if you had a large number of stripes:

```
public void doSomethingWithLocks() {
     doSomethingWithLock(0);
}

private void doSomethingWithLock(int stripe) {
     if (stripe < stripes.size()) {
         Lock lock = stripes.getAt(stripe);
         lock.lock();
         try {
             doSomethingWithLock(stripe + 1);
         } finally {
             lock.unlock();
         }
     } else {
         doSomething();
     }
}

private void doSomething() {
    // Do something
}
```